# Threading Error static assertion failed C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am actually doing a programm to simulate stuffs in c++ , However I have a big problem which is :
**error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues|**

I did actually made a lot of research but nothing came out and I dont know at all what to do my error is for std::thread AppliWaitThd(AppliMsgWait()); who is not a class and I dont know how to make it work. AppliMsgWait is just a while loop with action inside.

here is my code

```
#include "../Include/classglConfigCtx.h"
#include "../Include/SupSrv.h"
#include "../Include/ClassRadMgr.h"
#include "../Include/globalDefine.h"
#include "../Include/structGesCan.h"
#include "../Include/AppliMsg.h"
#include "../Include/AppliSNMP.h"
#include "../Include/GesCanSlot.h"
#include "../Include/GesCanSrv.h"

int main (){

SupSrv SupSrvFile("V0", "SupSrV.txt" );
ConfigClass ConfigCtx;
RadMgr RadioManager;
AppliMsgInit();
role InitRole ;
InitRole = ConfigCtx.ConfigClassGetrole_();

if (InitRole==masterRole)
    {
        GesCanSrvInit();
        GesCanSlotInit();
    };

std::thread RadMgrThd(&RadMgr::RadMgrWaitEvt,&RadioManager);

std::thread AppliWaitThd(AppliMsgWait());

std::thread AppliSNMPWaitThd(AppliSNMPWait());


if(InitRole==masterRole)
{
std::thread GesCanSrvThd(GesCanSrvRecvMsg());
std::thread GesCanSlotThd(GesCanSlotPeriod());

};



RadMgrThd.join();
AppliWaitThd.join();
AppliSNMPWaitThd.join();
//GesCanSrvThd.join();
//GesCanSlotThd.join();


return 0;
};
```

Here is my function

```
int AppliMsgWait(){
while(1)
{
// vérification des données du contexte de config?
    if(ConfigCtx.ConfigClassGetFlagChangeAddr_()==true) {
        auto newNetCastAddr= ConfigCtx.ConfigClassGetnetCastAddr_();
        auto newNeighCastAddr = ConfigCtx.ConfigClassGetneighCastAddr_();

        serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr= inet_addr(newNeighCastAddr.c_str());
        ConfigCtx.ConfigClassSetFlagChangeAddr_(false);

    }



    else if(glCSMAMsgToSCOMLst.size()>0) {

        AppliMsgSendSCOM();

    }
    else {

        AppliMsgRecvSCOM();
    }

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));

}//While
return 1 ;
}//end func
```

Comment: `std::thread AppliWaitThd(AppliMsgWait);` instead of `std::thread AppliWaitThd(AppliMsgWait());`, same for every other similar `std::thread`-instantiation,

Comment: Using parentheses means you intend to execute the method and pass its return value (in this case, an int).  You want to pass the method pointer itself, though, so don't call the method - remove the parens.  Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: @J...  thank you guys !! so Will it work if I have a void function with the same method?

Comment: @user15832441 You can pass anything [callable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable).  The docs answer so many questions...

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code and provide that as part of your question. As a new user here, also take the  [tour] and read [ask].